# find maximum resultant vector sum for a game of 2 players

Tags: algorithm, math, vector, data-structures, geometry

Problem statement:-
In a Two dimension plane there are 2K (x,y) coordinates given. Two people A and B are playing game of selecting any 1 coordinate from plane (no restriction in selecting) in one turn simultaneously. provide a strategy  to player A such that it has maximum resultant vector sum which is
Sqrt((x1 + x2 + x3 ... + xk)^2 + (y1 +y2+y3 +...yk)^2) meanwhile B is also equal competitor and playing with strategy.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the placement of the 2K points? Also, the problem needs to state whether the strategy of player B aims to (a) maximize its own resultant, (b) achieve a resultant larger than that of player A, or (c) minimize the resultant player A can achieve.

Comment: You know mini-max?

Comment: @dxiv no constraint on placement .our task is select K point turn by turn from randomly distributed 2K points on 2-dimensional plane.

Comment: and player B is also playing fair game to maximise it's own result.